# What am i doing wrong? Entries are not getting logged into database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

Here is Index:
It goes through folder and should add entries to database. But when i run it no entries are getting added. Is something wrong with this code? 
(Basically code goes through couple folders gets image file and songs under the folder and add to database, but it is not working.)

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {            
            DemoDb db = new DemoDb();
            var movies = new List<SongModel>();
            MovieModel movie = new MovieModel();
            SongModel song = new SongModel();
            //Function to get all the folders present in that particular location,Use
            var folders = Directory.GetDirectories(Server.MapPath("~/Content/themes/base/songs"));

            foreach (var folder in folders)
            {
                movie.MovieName = new DirectoryInfo(folder).Name;
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folder);
                string img = string.Empty;
                var list = new List<string>();
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    if (Path.GetExtension(file) == ".jpg" ||
                        Path.GetExtension(file) == ".png")
                    {
                        movie.Image = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/themes/base/songs"), file);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        song.MovieId = movie.MovieId;
                        song.Song = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/themes/base/songs"), file);                        
                    }     
                }
                db.movies.Add(movie);
                db.songs.Add(song);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }              
            return View();
        }
```

Here are classes and database design too:

```
public class MovieModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int MovieId { get; set; }
        public string MovieName { get; set; }
        public int SongId { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
    }
    public class SongModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int SongId { get; set; }
        public int MovieId { get; set; }
        public string Song { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Did you defined primary key in the database table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating only one movie and song above.
For every folder you overwrite the values in a movie object but never add a new object to your context, you only try to re-add your existing movie.
Also I wouldn't do this on an index HttpGet method. By the http spec a repeated GET call shouldn't change the system state each time (hence it should be idempotent)

Comment: But even if this overwrites it, should add atleast one entry in database right? But it is not adding anything? Can you show me some code what you mean by repeated GET? As if i use this to show lets say 100 folders in View wont the repeated calling take long time?

Comment: Also you aren't disposing of demodb when done either, and you only need to call save changes once after you have added all the entities.  I'll have to edit when back on laptop tomorrow, but yes you should have at least one entry in the DB. Sure you are checking the right database?